# Encoding::CompatibilityError in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

```
<%= link_to '注销', :controller => :user, :action => :logout %>
```

this raises Encoding::Compatibility exception, and when i try

```
<%= link_to '注销'.force_encoding('utf-8'), :controller => :user, :action => :logout %>
```

this didn't help, either. but this works

```
<a href="<%= url_for :controller => :user, :action => :logout>">注销</a>
```

why ??? i just can't figure out WHY this happends and HOW to fix it. any ideas?? thanks!!!
ruby version 1.9, rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got similar errors before and it turned out that the file itself that contains the code is not using UTF8 encoding :(, so you'd better check the editor you are using as it might not be using UTF8 encoded files.

Comment: seems like this only occurs in ruby1.9 , it works fine with ruby1.8.

Comment: Try adding this line at the begining of ur file:   # encoding: utf-8