# translated into Portuguese ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Someone can indicate me a tutorial to enable admin to translate the rails 3 for Portuguese or another language?

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: You must to convert your files in utf8. See this message http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962469/encodingcompatibilityerror-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

The active_admin translations is here: 
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/lib/active_admin/locales
choose one file, put it on your config/locales directory, change the first line with Portuguese locale, and start translating

Comment: not working special characters type á, ç, ã, ...    Encoding::CompatibilityError in Admin::MalfunctionsController#index

incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Comment: link is currently dead

Answer (score 0):

Encoding::CompatibilityError in Admin::MalfunctionsController#index

incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT